# Using an object's function inside object literal

Tags: javascript, function, object, object-literal

Is both defining a function and using it in a literal notation for an object possible?

```
var solution1 = {
  compute: function() {
    var toplam = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
      if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
        toplam += i;
    }
    return toplam;
  },
  answer: solution1.compute() //This is the problem.
}
```

Comment: yeah but it didnt work, Ammar's work great. Thanks both of you for answers

Answer (score 4):

At definition time, `solution1` will be `undefined`.

Use a [**getter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) instead like

```js
var solution1 = {
  compute: function() {
    var toplam = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
      if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
        toplam += i;
    }

    return toplam;
  },
  get answer() {
    return this.compute();
  }

};

console.log(solution1.answer);
```

Comment: Thank you, as i moved the logic to classes, this also saved me from defining solution[i].answer = solution[i].compute() everytime, just what i needed!

Comment: I wonder if you could simply give that function a name or just reference it as "compute", ie, no "this"